# How are inital states established in dynamic models under Electrum 2?

Tags: alloy

I cribbed from the hotel door lock example and came up with this MWE for vehicle doors.

```
enum LockState {Locked, Unlocked}

sig Door {
    var state: LockState
}

sig Vehicle {
     doors :  disj set Door
}

//actions
pred unlock[d: Door]{
    d.state' = Unlocked
}

pred lock[d: Door]{
    d.state' = Locked
}

//traces
pred init{
    all s: Door.state | s = Locked
}

pred trace{
    init
    always {
        some d: Door | 
            unlock[d] or
            lock[d]
    }
}

//demonstrate
run {} for 4 but exactly 2 Vehicle, 4 Time
```

Which to my suprise allows the instance shown below, in which some doors are locked and some not. How do I establish the condition that all doors are locked at the earliest time?
[image: instance of the above model showing some doors locked and some unlocked at all times.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial states are defined without any temporal keywords, as you did in init.

The problem is that you defined your `trace` as a predicate. If you define it as a `fact` it will always be applied. However, if you make it a predicate (my preference since it feels less *global*) you **must** include it from the run command. Pick one:

```
run trace for 4 but exactly 2 Vehicle, 4 Time
run  { trace } for 4 but exactly 2 Vehicle, 4 Time
```

However, your model will then still not run well.

- You provide an `always` but no goal. So after one state Alloy is happy. You should provide an `eventually` so Alloy will attempt to continue until it is satisfied.
- You allow vehicles without doors, I would use `some Door` instead of `set Door`
- Your `init` can be done cleaner like `Door.state = Locked`
- In your trace, each *step* sets one Door. However, you're not specifying what the state of the other doors should be. If you do not specify a value for the next state, they can become anything. These should be explicitly set to have their old value.

So I came up with the following model:

```
enum LockState { Locked, Unlocked }
sig Door       { var state: LockState }
sig Vehicle    { doors :  disj some Door }

pred Door.unlock { this.state' = Unlocked }
pred Door.lock   { this.state' = Locked }

pred trace {
    Door.state = Locked
    always (
        some d: Vehicle.doors {
            (d.unlock or d.lock) 
            unchanged[state,d]

        }
    )
    eventually Door.state = Unlocked
}

run trace for 4 but exactly 2 Vehicle


pred unchanged[ r : univ->univ, x : set univ ] {
    (r - x->univ)' = (r - x->univ)
}
```

**updated** Added an unchanged predicate.